How to size parallel connections in a battery pack?
I am building a battery for an electric motorcycle. I have 4 EV modules that are 44.4v (12S, 400A peak output) that I plan on putting in a 2p2s layout (88.8v, 800A peak). I know the series connections need to be able to handle the full current (800A). As such, my "total" positive and "total" negative wires connecting to the load will be significantly larger (2x 4awg).
However, the parallel connections I am less certain on because, based on my understanding, they are mostly used to balance the load and make sure both cells are kept at the same voltage. I was planning on connecting each of the cells in parallel using a significantly smaller wire size (20awg) because I can't imagine needing more than 10A between the cells. Plus each module is in its own case and getting larger wires between cells would require destructively modifying that case. Then I also plan on using those parallel connections as the balance leads back to the BMS (which typically just need the balancing current of 2A).
Here is an example drawing with just 4s:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
Am I sizing my parallel connections properly?


Am I sizing my parallel connections properly?

Theoretically yes, because, if all the cells are perfectly identical and all the wire lengths are the same and all the connections are perfect, then there is no current through the connections between parallel cells; the current is divided equally between the two cells in parallel.
However, in the real world, cells differ (and do so increasingly over time), wire lengths differ, and some connections have more resistance than others. Consequently, the current doesn't divide equally. That's why you want the connections between two parallel cells to be as hefty as the connection between cells in series. It's possible that the instantaneous current at the start of acceleration is carried mostly by one cell, not both equally. If so, that current could melt a thin wire used to parallel cells.

Thanks for your response! A little outside the scope of the question.. would it then be better to not have the parallel connections in between cells and just have it on the main positive and negative of each module where I can fit appropriately sized cables? And then have two separate BMSes to balance the parallel modules (potentially master/2x slave)?

No, oh no. That would be worse. The way you're doing it is correct. Just place cells physically next to each other if you can. That way the parallel connections are no problem. If you must have two separate boxes, then connect two 7.2 V boxes in series. That is, each box has a 2P2S arrangement. Once connected in series, that gives you 14.4 V.
